# How can I build very big matrix in svg

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, canvas, svg

I need to build a matrix of 10000X10000 in canvas/svg. In each cell I need to create a square. I tried to do that with canvas in 2 loops like that:

```js
for(i=0; i<10000; i++){
  for(j=0;j<10000; j++){
    /*some code of drwing*/
    console.log(i,',',j);
  }
}
```

But this loops take a lot of time. How can I draw big matrix in good performance?
(I need that every cell in the matrix will behave differently depending on the matrix of objects that I get from the database)

Thanks

Comment: What does "behave differently" mean? Different shapes/colors/sizes?

Comment: yes. background color and text inside

Comment: I can give you an answer but I need to know what you are using the array for? Do you intend to print it? or is it only for display on the screen?

Answer (score 1):

You're most likely best off doing your drawing using canvas, here's why:

While SVG can be rather straight forward to work with, it can easily get expensive to draw (see [this article, for example](https://www.sitepoint.com/canvas-vs-svg-choosing-the-right-tool-for-the-job/)), even if you only do one live DOM insertion as demonstrated below.

```js
function createSvgElement(tag, props) {
  var el = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", tag);
  for (prop in props) {
    el.setAttributeNS(null, prop, props[prop]);
  }
  return el;
}

var svg = document.getElementById('svg');

document.getElementById('input').onclick = function render() {
  var start = new Date();
  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  for (var x = 0; x < 400; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < 400; y++) {
      var circle = createSvgElement('circle', {
        'cx': x,
        'cy': y,
        'r': 0.2,
        'fill': 'red'
      });
      fragment.appendChild(circle);
    }
  }
  svg.appendChild(fragment);
  var time = new Date() - start;
  document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(time + 'ms'));
}
```

```css
svg {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="button" value="render svg" />
<svg id="svg" width="400" height="400"></svg>
```

The main issue with SVG is, no matter how much you do on your end to reduce work for the browser, in the end, the DOM will still have thousands of elements that the browser has to figure out how to render by itself.

---

Working with canvas will mean noticeably more work for you, especially if you want to do fancy styles, but as you're relieving the browser of most of the rendering logic (and handling it yourself), it can be a lot faster.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

document.getElementById('input').onclick = function render() {
  var start = new Date();
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  for (var x = 0; x < 400; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < 400; y++) {
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(x, y, 0.2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      context.fillStyle = 'red';
      context.fill();
      context.closePath();
    }
  }
  var time = new Date() - start;
  document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(time + 'ms'));
}
```

```css
canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="button" value="render canvas" />
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

*Addendum: I don't use canvas often so there may be a better way to do what I wrote above, however, it will suffice to illustrate the difference.*

Comment: The Op is asking to layout and draw 100 million items. This is beyond the scope of any home PC so I can not say your answer is at all helpful.. The solution is dependent on what the display medium is to be.

Comment: @Blindman67 Given the question is tagged with `html5` and `canvas`, it seems rather clear that the intended medium is a screen. Drawing only the items that are cropped to the view, visualizing that amount of object won't really be an issue if you approach it right. This answer addresses exactly that issue, how to do it right. Using canvas over SVG can offer magnitudes of performance gains in the described scenario.

Comment: The question involves SVG so the inference that this is only intended for the screen is not given. I have read your answer a second time and you do not give any clear indication that you intend only for the visual part to be rendered, nor do you show how to effectively locate and render the visible section. I think that all your answer needs is to meantion that doing such is the answer to the problem (if indeed the content is only for display)

Comment: @Blindman67 If you think the answer is lacking you're free to write one yourself.